# How to reference custom screen in its own customization project in another customization project

Tags: acumatica

I have a customization project that contains custom tables, DACs, and screens which use them.  This project is in a class library project created in Visual Studio.

I also have another customization project (a class library also) that needs to post data into that custom screen, but since that custom screen is not part of Acumatica - I can't extend the graph of that screen (that I know of), and if I re-create the DACs for that screen in my new project - will that result in problems due to duplicate DACs for the same table deployed at the same time?

To summarize:  I need to manipulate a custom screen from another customization project in different customization project - and I'm not sure of the best way to do that.    Can I just provide the dlls from my first customization project as a reference in my new project?

I realize that I can do this in a code window in Acumatica - but I have no access to syntax checking, intellisense, etc., so that's not really an option at this point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should simply reference the dlls (or the VS projects) from your first customization project in your second VS project. Once you provide those 2 completed packages to the client, make sure they always publish both projects at the same time or only the first one, which has no dependencies on another project.

Comment: Ruslan's post is the answer. In your 2nd project just include the dll as a reference in visual studio and you can build the customization, use intellisence, etc. But do not include the depended dll in the 2nd customization package, only the first. Then publish the 2 together. You can create a graph extension in the 2nd customization project. I have done this before and works great.